# why should the models used by modeltime_table be adjusted on the training data when applying modeltime_fit_resamples ?( modeltime )

Tags: r, time-series, tidymodels

When working with time series through the modeltime / tidymodels framework, the following workflow is presented to verify the performance of the models with cross validation.

```
library(modeltime)
library(modeltime.resample)
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)

resamples_tscv <- time_series_cv(
    data        = m750,
    assess      = "2 years",
    initial     = "5 years",
    skip        = "2 years",
    slice_limit = 4
)

resamples_tscv
```

```
## # Time Series Cross Validation Plan 
## # A tibble: 4 x 2
##   splits          id    
##   <list>          <chr> 
## 1 <split [60/24]> Slice1
## 2 <split [60/24]> Slice2
## 3 <split [60/24]> Slice3
## 4 <split [60/24]> Slice4
```

Once the cross-validation floods have been obtained, the performance of the models is evaluated using the modeltime_fit_resamples function, passing the m750_models object as a parameter. This item contains 3 fitted models.

```
resamples_fitted <- m750_models %>%
    modeltime_fit_resamples(
        resamples = resamples_tscv,
        control   = control_resamples(verbose = FALSE)
    )

resamples_fitted
```

```
## # Modeltime Table
## # A tibble: 3 x 4
##   .model_id .model     .model_desc             .resample_results
##       <int> <list>     <chr>                   <list>           
## 1         1 <workflow> ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12] <tibble [4 × 5]> 
## 2         2 <workflow> PROPHET                 <tibble [4 × 5]> 
## 3         3 <workflow> GLMNET                  <tibble [4 × 5]>
```

Here I have a doubt, in the workflow of tidymodels (excluding time series) when we use the function fit_resamples to evaluate the performance of the models, the models are not adjusted, they only have the hyperparameters updated if it were the case, it does not apply the function fit on the training data, the idea is that this fit is made on each partition "train / test" of cross validation.

```
m750_models
```

```
## # Modeltime Table
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   .model_id .model     .model_desc            
##       <int> <list>     <chr>                  
## 1         1 <workflow> ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12]
## 2         2 <workflow> PROPHET                
## 3         3 <workflow> GLMNET
```

However when inspecting the m750_models object, all 3 models are already fitted. Shouldn't the models fit on each "train / test" partition? Or am I misunderstanding the procedure? Below I show a workflow using fit_resamples

```
library(tidymodels
data("hpc_data")

svm_spec <- svm_poly(degree = 1, cost = 1/4) %>%
  set_engine("kernlab") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

svm_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(svm_spec) %>%
  add_formula(compounds ~ .)

hpc_folds <- vfold_cv(hpc_data)

svm_rs <- svm_wf %>%
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = hpc_folds
  )

svm_rs
#> # Resampling results
#> # 10-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    splits             id     .metrics         .notes          
#>    <list>             <chr>  <list>           <list>          
#>  1 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold01 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  2 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold02 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  3 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold03 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  4 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold04 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  5 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold05 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  6 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold06 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  7 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold07 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  8 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold08 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  9 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold09 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 10 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold10 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
```

Comment: The function `fit_resamples()` does fit on each fold using the specified model, typically with the purpose of evaluating performance. In each `split`, the model is fit to the "analysis" set and then is evaluated on the "assessment" set. If you would like to read more, you [can check out this chapter.](https://www.tmwr.org/resampling.html)

Comment: Perfect, I agree with you. But the input of the `modeltime_fit_resamples` function is a
"Modeltime Table" that is generated with the `modeltime_table` function (in this case the m750_models object), where the models must already be trained.

My question is related to the difference in the inputs of the `fit_resamples` and `modeltime_fit_resamples` functions, I am used to using fit_resamples the way you have exposed it in multiple tutorials, fitting the models without training (or with the best hyperparameters with `finalize_workflow` ) in each of the splits.

Comment: Or internally `modeltime_fit_resamples` extracts the recipe and the model specification to recreate the workflow without training and thus adjust it to each split? sorry if I did not understand well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe understanding the procedure a bit more will help. When you [Modeltime Resample](https://business-science.github.io/modeltime.resample/) is designed to take your **model's specification** and refit it repeatedly to resampled data.

### What is resampling?

It's the idea that we want to test how our models would have performed given that the models were trained on subsets of the data. This is useful in understanding our confidence in the models and how it changes especially with time series (temporal) data. Resampling require re-training and re-evaluating the **model specification** on each resample (train/test 1, train/test 2, ..., train/test N).

### What is a model specification?

- It's the parameters you've specified and model type (modeling function and engine)
- It's *not* the "Fitted Model" (meaning it doesn't make predictions with your model)

### How does the internal Modeltime Resample process work?

1. Modeltime Resample uses the `fit_resamples()` function from `tune` and applies to each model in a modeltime table containing one or more models.
2. The refitting process ignores your "fitted model", but copies the parameters selected and the modeling specification to repeated fit (train) new models to the resamples.
3. The result is how your model would have performed if fitted on different samples of the data. You can display the results using the plotting and table utilities.

### Resample Table and Resample Plot

Examples from the [Panel Data Tutorial](https://business-science.github.io/modeltime.resample/articles/panel-data.html):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect , thank you very much for your explanation.